# git add multiple times without commit

Tags: git

I notice that if I edit a file in my repo, stage it but don't commit it, edit it again, stage it again but don't commit etc. then for each time I do this a new snapshot is taken and the disk space increases.

Furthermore, if I stage 5 times following tiny edits and finally *commit* once after all stagings, the disk space of the repo still increases approximately 5x the file size.

My question is, why doesn't git just forget about the other staged versions if only the latest one has a commit sha1 reference to the state?  The other 4 staged versions will be garbage collected?  Is there a way to checkout a staged state which was never committed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### TL;DR

See [`git fsck --lost-found`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck#git-fsck---lost-found).

#### Longer, point-by-point

> My question is, why doesn't git just forget about the other staged versions if only the latest one has a commit sha1 reference to the state?

It does ... eventually.

> The other 4 staged versions will be garbage collected?

Yes, when `git gc` eventually runs automatically.  If you want this to happen sooner, you can run `git gc` yourself, but there's only rarely any reason to bother (the common case being *oops, I did not mean to `git add 10terabytes.db`*).<sup>1</sup>

> Is there a way to checkout a staged state which was never committed?

Sort of.  The `git checkout` command cannot do it because `git checkout` works by *file* names, and these staged content-only blobs have no file name.  They have only a hash ID.  To extract their data, you must first find their hash ID.  This is easy to do: you just checksum the data the way Git would, which just means that you need to have the data available first, in order to get the data. :-)

Alternatively, you can do much of what `git gc` does, which is:

- Enumerate every object ID in the object database.
- Enumerate every *reachable* object ID.  For details on reachability, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).  Note that reachability here includes all reflog entries for all references, and all index and `HEAD` entries from all active work-trees.<sup>2</sup>
- Subtract the second set of object IDs (reachable) from the first set of IDs (all).  The resulting IDs are unreferenced, i.e., objects that are candidates for garbage collection.

(This is a bit slow, but `git fsck` does it for you, so that you do not have to write code to do it.)

From the set of all unreachable objects, select those that have type *blob*, i.e., files that were `git add`ed but never committed.  Inspect each blob, using its hash ID to access it, to see if it is the one you wanted.  Here `git cat-file -p` is useful, or use `git fsck --lost-found`, which takes each such blob, de-compresses it, and writes the data to an ordinary file in `.git/lost-found/other/`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that you may also need `--prune=` options: `git gc` defaults to giving other Git processes 14 days to complete the job of hooking up objects.  If you use `--prune=all`, make sure no other Git activity is occurring.

<sup>2</sup>When you remember to include work-trees added via `git worktree add`, you will be doing something the Git folks forgot to do.  This is a particularly nasty bug, present in Git version 2.5 through 2.14.*: work being done in an added work-tree can be pruned via an automatic `git gc`, if you've left that work-tree idle for 2 weeks or more.  If you are using `git worktree add`, I recommend making sure your Git is at least version 2.15.

Comment: Git garbage collection (`gc`) by default removes loose (unreferenced) objects older than 2 weeks. If you want to you can set a different date or remove all loose objects with `git gc --prune=<date, or 'all'>`, see: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#git-gc---pruneltdategt

Comment: @ScottNewson: right, this comes from the configuration slot in `gc.pruneExpire`. When I describe using `git prune` (vs `git gc`) I go into more detail: `git prune` requires being careful not to run it while other Git activities are occurring.